# Is it possible to post data into a curl url?

Tags: php, json, curl

So I'm trying to post a value from the following form into a cURL url (the script name is pagination.php) like so:

```
<form action="pagination.php" method="post">
<input style="width:50%" type="text" name="search_term">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];

echo $search_term;

$post_data = array('q' => $search_term);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds
/api/videos?q='.urlencode($search_term).'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&
v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($output,true);

$info = $data["feed"];
$video = $info["entry"];
$nVideo = count($video);



echo "<ul style='float:right'>";
foreach($video as $video) {
echo '<img src="'.$video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'].'"><br><br>';
$title = $video['title']['$t'];
$video_id = $video['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t'];
echo '<a href="search_4.php?video_get_id='.$video_id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
echo '<br>'; 
}
```

When I run the code like this nothing happens (and yes I echoed out $search_term to make sure it wasn't empty), however if I manually assign a value to $search_term like this

```
$search term = 'baseball';
```

everything works fine. Is there something about cURL that doesn't allow posted data? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're mising

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

**EDIT**
Now answering the unasked question "How do I make this work?"

Like @Kostanos said, looks like the problem was line-breaks in your url. This works:

```
<form action="pagination.php" method="post">
<input style="width:50%" type="text" name="search_term">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if($_POST)
  {
    $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];

    echo $search_term;

    $post_data = array('q' => $search_term);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='.urlencode($search_term).'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($output,true);

    $info = $data["feed"];
    $video = $info["entry"];
    $nVideo = count($video);



    echo "<ul style='float:right'>";
    foreach($video as $video)
    {
      echo '<img src="'.$video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'].'"><br><br>';
      $title = $video['title']['$t'];
      $video_id = $video['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t'];
      echo '<a href="search_4.php?video_get_id='.$video_id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
      echo '<br>';
    }

  }
```

Comment: does it matter where I put those lines? I edited my code above please let me know if you think I did it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, it looks like you're sending a GET request anyway, so I answered your actual question but didn't solve your problem. So, like @kostanos said, carefully construct the query string in your GET request and you should get the right return without the lines I mentioned.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and everything works perfectly when I set $search_term to a constant like $search_term = 'baseball'. But when search term is set to $search_term = $_POST['search_term']; nothing works. That is literally the only change I make in the code. And when I echo out $search term to make sure a value actually posted I get a result.

Comment: What happens when you echo out `$_POST['search_term']`?

Comment: The value is there...the issue is definitely not that the value isn't posting...in fact, if I assign the url to a variable and then echo out that variable, the url does have the correct search term in it...what's weirder is that the script doesn't stop working...instead, yahoo defaults to another video feed that has nothing to do with the search term. You really have to run the code to see what I mean.

Comment: Take a look at the EDIT I just did on my answer.

Comment: Oh I actually tried that...and when I echo out $url_to_submit the result does have the correct search term in the q variable...which makes it all the more confusing.

Comment: when you run the code with your suggested changes does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code:

```
...
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $search_term);
...
```

$search_form is not correct POSTFIELDS value, it should be the `key=>value` paired array or string like this: `&key=value&key1=value1..`

Try to use this:

```
...
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
$post_data = array('q' => $search_term);
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
...
```

BTW: **For youtube API**

You don't need the POST request, just GET request. Remove these two lines from your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $search_term);
```

And replace this line (be sure that it is one line, without any enters in the string, it seems that your editor add enter to the long string!):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' . urlencode($search_term) . '&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50');
```

PS. By adding urlencode to the $search_term

Comment: Thanks... I made the changes you suggested (I edited my code above as well) and I'm still getting nothing.

Comment: I just checked your script it works well, please be sure that the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='.urlencode($search_term).'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50');`
has no enters, it should be in one line!

Comment: It's so weird that the code works for you. I even tried assigning the url to a variable and then echoing out the variable to make sure there weren't any spaces. It must be a small error I'm making somewhere else.

Comment: I added it to my answer, but Kostanos has it right. You have linebreaks in your URL causing problems. Kill the linebreaks (put the URL all in one line in your editor) and it will fix the problem.